# Placeholder: the default text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want a small code for my textbox validation. Basically I want to input digit number in a textbox only.

Now my code is working, but I can't remove the default placeholder text.

```
<div id="generatePinsDialog" title="Generate New PINs">
    <label>How many will be generated?
        <span style="position: relative;">
            <input id="newInmateCount" name="text" maxLength="6" type="text" placeholder="Enter the number" />
            <label style="font: 0.75em/normal sans-serif; left: 5px; top: 3px; width: 147px; height: 15px; color: rgb(186, 186, 186); position: absolute; overflow-x: hidden; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal;" for="newInmateCount">Enter the number!    
            </label>
       </span>
    </label>
    <br />
</div>
```

And

```
$("#newInmateCount").data("defTxt", $("#newInmateCount").val());
$("#newInmateCount").bind("blur focus", function (e) {
    $(this).val($(this).val() == $("#newInmateCount").data("defTxt") ? "" : $("#newInmateCount").data("defTxt"));
});


$("#newInmateCount").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) return true;
    if (e.which < 48 || (e.which > 57 && e.which < 96) || e.which > 105) return false;
});
```

The [link.](http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/mGAPs/9/)

Comment: Why not use an written watermark plugin? Such as [this one](http://the.deerchao.net/PlaceHolder).

Comment: Can't remove the placeholder? Only because you've put another field over the top. The placeholder attribute should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `<label>`: you already have the `placeholder` attribute on your `<input>`, which should behave exactly as you say you want. But you also have a `<label>` positioned *over* the field, and that's messing up everything.

Just get rid of the label, and the placeholder text will disappear when you enter a number into the field.

See an [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mGAPs/10/).

Comment: Ditto. Your field has placeholder. You don't need to also fake one.

Comment: Just remove the `<label>` element. See an [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mGAPs/10/).

Comment: I use IE 9, I don't know why it is working in jsfiddle but failed in real project. The watermark didn't show at all.

Comment: Indeed, it won't work on IE (see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder)). But there are some workarounds (see [here](http://the.deerchao.net/PlaceHolder), [here](https://github.com/parndt/jquery-html5-placeholder-shim), [here](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) and [here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills))

Answer (score 0):

You've placed your second label over the input field.
These placeholders are browser generated. You shouldn't try to fake that.

Also the nesting of the first label is wrong.

This works and looks much better http://jsfiddle.net/mGAPs/11/

```
 <div id="generatePinsDialog" title="Generate New PINs">
 <label for="newInmateCount">How many will be generated?</label>
 <input id="newInmateCount" name="text" maxLength="6" type="text" placeholder="Enter the number" />
 </div>
```

**EDIT**

You can fix this HTML5 behavior also for IE9

```
$('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.val('');
    input.removeClass('placeholder');
  }
}).blur(function() {
  var input = $(this);
  if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
    input.addClass('placeholder');
    input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
  }
}).blur();
```

The down side is that you need to change your first bit of jquery (which also uses focus and blur)
I've disabeled it in this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mGAPs/12/

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the @Jeroen answers and even use the html5 "number" type

```
<div id="generatePinsDialog" title="Generate New PINs">
    <label for="newInmateCount">How many will be generated?</label>
    <input id="newInmateCount" name="text" step="1" min="0" max="999999" type="number" placeholder="Enter the number" />
</div>
```

For cross-browser compatibility you better use third party plugins like [this one](http://the.deerchao.net/PlaceHolder) suggested above

Comment: suggestion is to use third party already tested and approved by the community plugins

Comment: In my answer I noticed that you also use focus and blur functions. You should review that part of the code. Most of these plugins use these functions as well. I guess thats why you're having trouble getting those plugins to work.